# Redirect desktop users .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

my links are
 www.website.com/link1.xml
www.website.com/link2.xml

so i like those links to be viewed just from mobile user and if someone from pc try to go to this link it will redirect to another link

i try this but it dont works  so if you have a solution please share

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(MSIE.*Windows\ NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ about/ [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(MSIE.*Windows\ NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror) [NC]
RewriteRule \.xml$ about/ [L,R]
```